# How can I retrieve specific data from sql in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I have a database with the following table:

[image: users table]

I am trying to get the role of the current username so I can redirect that person to the right page. I tried it with the if clause (acc.u_role == 1), but it doesn't work unfortunately.

```
    public ActionResult Verify(User acc)
    {
        connectionString();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "select * from Users where u_username = '"+acc.u_username+"' and u_password ='"+acc.u_password+"'";

        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (acc.u_role == 1) { 
                con.Close();
                return View("AdminHome");
            }
            else
            {
                con.Close();
                return View("UserHome");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, from a database to another, you can't guarantee that your role id will be 1. Instead, I'd simply return the name of the role linked to this user so you know the role for good and base your redirection on it.

Comment: 3 quick tips: 1: parameterize your sql, 2: `connectionString()` is not a good method name, use verbs and descriptive names. 3: learn about try/catch/finally.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting acc.u_role?

It looks like you're reading the data and then not using it. dr[5] should contain the role from the database

```
        dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        { 

            if (dr[5] == 1) { 
                con.Close();
                return View("AdminHome");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution to my answer, here it is:

```
 if (dr.Read())
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["u_role"]) == 1) {
                    con.Close();
                    return View("AdminHome");
                }
                else
                {
                    con.Close();
                    return View("UserHome");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                con.Close();
                return View("Error");
            }
```

Comment: What you propably want to use is ExecuteScalar(). You only need as single return value - the u_role of a specific user. Retreiving too much data to then do filtering in the Progrmam is a very common mistake. It is right up there with not using Parametized Queries in mistakes to avoid.